# hand-controls component support in A-Frame 0.9.0

Tags: aframe

I'm working on a research project employing A-Frame. Although the documentation for A-Frame suggests using the hand-controls component to abstract Oculus Touch and Vive controllers, the implementation as listed in the documentation doesn't seem to work with the latest iteration of A-Frame.

Because we'd like to make a sustainable build, I'd rather not use an earlier version that plays nice with hand-controls (currently using 0.9.0); however, I'd also like to employ the officially supported A-Frame components in solutions where possible.
Is there a new implementation not listed in the docs? The write-up for hand-controls looks like it was last updated at least 2 years ago.

I'd just thought I'd ask for tips before employing my own solution. The oculus-touch-controls component seems to be functioning fine (I haven't tested vive-controls yet), so I plan on developing my own solution if hand-controls is broken in the current build.

source from A-Frame: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/hand-controls.js

documentation from A-Frame: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/hand-controls.md

listing in API documentation on A-Frame site: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/hand-controls.html#sidebar

Thanks!

Comment: There was a bug, use master: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@9fadc40c180c43f198f893d4867209ca3c19bf93/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Comment: If still doesn’t work, elaborate. What part doesn’t work? Provide a link with a test case to reproduce the issue. Glitch is good: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Ah that did it, thanks for the help! I'll look to use the master in the future, oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting full answer, this is a bug fixed in latest versiosn of A-Frame post 0.9.0. 0.9.1 with fixes will be released soon.